# error al hacer un ejecutable con py2exe en un juego de pygame

Tags: python, pygame

yo queria hacer un ejecutable de un juego de pygame, hice el procedimiento normal con el setup y termino el proceso. intente abrir el ejecutable pero me da el siguiente error al abrirlo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

`File "menu.py", line 112, in <module>`
`File "menu.py", line 31, in __init__`
`File "pygame\pkgdata.pyc", line 84, in getResource`
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\miusuario\\Desktop\\dist\\library.zip\\pygame\\freesansbold.ttf'`

si me pueden ayudar **Gracias**

Comment: aparentemente falta algo del path : C:\\Users\\miusuario\\Desktop\\dist\\library.zip\\pygame\\freesansbold.ttf  deberías fijarte como has cargado la fuente y el directorio que le asignaste.

Comment: hola, como hago eso?

Comment: pues en el script estás agregando un path para la fuente, simplemente elimina el path y deja la fuente en el mismo directorio del script, copiando allí la fuente.

Comment: lo siento, pero sigo sin entender

Answer (score 0):

pongo un ejemplo para que lo compiles y pruebes, ya que supongo sabes usar pygame:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Prueba de texto")

fuente=pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
texto = fuente.render("Ejemplo de texto",0,(200,60,80))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            
    ventana.blit(texto,(100,100))
    pygame.display.update()
```

es una simple ventana con un texto pero :

```
fuente=pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
```

ésta línea que asigna la fuente es la que creo debes revisar, asigno la fuente, que copié en el mismo lugar donde está el script.
Entonces al compilar la fuente estará en el mismo lugar que el exe y debería funcionar.

Como comentario, py2exe da problemas con algunos antivirus, prefiero usar cx_Freeze

Comment: Gracias!! ya lo solucione!!, antes de que viera tu respuesta intente usar cx_Freeze pero me perdi aun mas, pero ya lo arregle ¡Gracias a ti puedo publicar mi juego!